# Using Java1.7, Apostrophe being replaced with ? after Obtaining JSON

Tags: java, json

Using Java 1.7 and Spring MVC, I am getting a String which contains the following value (from an external datasource):

```
{ "fullName" : "Pedro Morález" }
```

But when I print it out or log it the actual value is:

```
"Pedro Mor?lez"
```

Here's my code:

```
String response = restTemplate.getForObject(new URI(feedUrl), String.class);
logger.info("Response: " + response);
```

How can I keep the apostrophe or just make it a plain "a"?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28742831/1553851

Comment: How do you know it's not your terminal with a bad character encoding?