# Local polish character support for return type of api in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, response, multilingual, polish

I am using springboot version = 1.5.13.RELEASE.
If I return data using object in Response Entity by first way shows below it returns character  **Ã**  as **Ã\u008d**
 and if I return same by converting object into String using ObjectMapper by second way and return it as Response Entity of String then it returns character **Ã as Ã** correctly.
Could you please why it gives issue if I use object in ResponseEntity as output.
Does I need to do any configuration. I also tried with MimeType of UTF-8 using (.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)) but it also  does not worked .
 Kindly help

**1) Return object in ResponseEntity**

```
 @GetMapping("v1/testAPI")
            @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") 
            public ResponseEntity<TESTClass> gettstDetails(@RequestParam(value = "param", required = false) String param){
    TESTClass objTESTClass= new TESTClass();
 objTESTClass.setOutputA("-BRASÃLIA BR");

 return ResponseEntity.ok(objTESTClass) ;
        }
```

**1) Return String in ResponseEntity**

```
     @GetMapping("v1/testAPI")
                    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") 
                    public ResponseEntity<String> gettstDetails(@RequestParam(value = "param", required = false) String param){
            TESTClass objTESTClass= new TESTClass();
         objTESTClass.setOutputA("-BRASÃLIA BR");
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

return ResponseEntity.ok( objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objTESTClass));
                }
```

and my TESTClass is like below

```
public class TESTClass{
    @JsonProperty("outputA")
    private String outputA;
    @JsonProperty("outputB")
    private String outputB;

    public String getOutputA() {
        return outputA;
    }

    public void setOutputA(String outputA) {
        this.outputA= outputA;
    }

    public String getOutputB() {
        return outputb;
    }

    public void setOutputB(String outputb) {
        this.outputB= outputB;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by using below code, followed below thread
[Java Spring resttemplate character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603782/java-spring-resttemplate-character-encoding)

RestTemplate objRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();

```
objRestTemplate.getMessageConverters()
                .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName(UaofConstants.UTF_8)));
```