# Disable Encoding Process on RestTemplate Springboot XML Request

Tags: java, xml, encode, spring-resttemplate

Is it possible to disable encoding process when request XML with RestTemplate?

I need to send my value like this
ud=HELLOOOO YEYEYE©À¥¥didiwawa©yayuÀ

```
ud=HELLOOOO YEYEYE&#x1f97a;&#x1f97a;&#xa9;&#xc0;&#xa5;&#xa5;didi&#x1f97a;wawa&#xa9;yayu&#xc0;
```

This is my request

```
  defaultUriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
  restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(defaultUriBuilderFactory);
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_XML));
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
  HttpEntity<Message> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);

   ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString(), httpEntity, String.class);
```

when I check the log, my request look like this on restTemplate process

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ud type="text">HELLOOOO YEYEYE&amp;#x1f97a;&amp;#x1f97a;&amp;#xa9;&amp;#xc0;&amp;#xa5;&amp;#xa5;didi&amp;#x1f97a;wawa&amp;#xa9;yayu&amp;#xc0;</ud>
```

I want my value parse to xml but without encoding process.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/28742831 ?

Comment: my code didn't convert at all. it just like object.toString(). I would like to parse my value to be xml format but without encoding the special character "&" -> "&amp;"

Comment: I think it's not possible to escape the special character due to invalid format for xml itself. We need to create it as stringify