Rest Template Returns Response in Garbled Characters Some Sort of Chinese
I am using rest template to call API, when I hit the API using rest template it returns some garbled characters like Chinese.
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, entity, String.class);

When I hit the same API using Unirest or Postman, it returns response in JSON. I searched and tried to figure it out but there is a constraint that I can't do changes in the code either I do change in application.yml or pom.xml but can not change at the code level.
<200,笀∀爀攀焀甀攀猀琀䐀愀琀攀吀椀洀攀∀㨀∀㈀　㈀㐀ⴀ　㜀ⴀ㈀㌀吀㄀　㨀㈀㄀㨀㄀㠀⸀㜀　㜀㘀㐀㄀㐀⬀　㔀㨀　　∀Ⰰ∀氀漀最䤀搀∀㨀∀㈀㜀　　㄀㜀昀戀ⴀ　攀㤀戀ⴀ㐀㐀戀搀ⴀ㤀搀　㠀ⴀ㔀㔀㄀㄀㌀㔀搀㜀搀　戀昀∀Ⰰ∀挀漀搀攀∀㨀∀䴀匀䜀ⴀ　　　　　　∀Ⰰ∀猀攀瘀攀爀椀琀礀∀㨀∀匀甀挀挀攀猀猀∀Ⰰ∀挀漀渀琀攀渀琀∀㨀∀攀礀䨀栀戀䜀挀椀伀椀䨀䤀唀稀䤀㄀一椀䤀猀䤀渀刀㔀挀䌀䤀㘀䤀欀瀀堀嘀䌀䨀㤀⸀攀礀䨀㄀戀洀氀砀搀圀嘀昀戀洀䘀琀娀匀䤀㘀䤀洀䤀㐀娀䐀䔀㈀䴀圀䔀礀䰀圀夀㈀夀樀挀琀一䐀䴀砀一礀㄀栀夀樀䔀　䰀吀欀㌀䴀䐀最稀伀吀䴀㐀娀圀䔀㐀䴀椀䤀猀䤀洀㔀椀娀椀䤀㘀䴀吀挀礀䴀吀挀砀䴀樀䄀㌀伀䌀眀椀娀堀栀眀䤀樀漀砀一稀䤀砀一稀䔀㄀一樀挀㐀䰀䌀䨀瀀夀堀儀椀伀樀䔀㌀䴀樀䔀㌀䴀吀䤀眀一稀栀㤀⸀挀䤀䄀攀䈀砀ⴀ瘀爀吀娀匀㠀㤀㠀甀㈀䄀㔀娀䰀㔀䴀倀䔀愀　爀欀伀儀瘀堀漀ⴀ樀ⴀ洀䤀礀唀　　∀Ⰰ∀攀爀爀漀爀∀㨀渀甀氀氀紀,{Content-Length=[780], Content-Type=[application/json; charset=utf-16], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/10.0], Date=[Tue, 23 Jul 2024 05:21:18 GMT]}>

This is the response I get.
And I want response in the below format.
<200,{requestDateTime=2024-07-23T10:23:45.9429614+05:00, logId=e7dc9988-2a2a780b54c6, code=200, severity=Success, content=eyJNiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJhbGciOiJIUzI19.eyJ1bSI6ImI4ZDE2MWEyMTIyMjV9LWY2mlxdWVfbmFtZYjctNDMcyMTcxMjIyNSwiZXhwIjoxNzIxNzE1ODI1LCJpYXQiOjE3MjxNy1hYjE0LTk3MDgzOTM4ZWE4MiIsIm5iZiI6MTE3.yGUCZ83YVYw7XOuXrIl79ONCYVuxKS5MbtB_XxG9wyE, error=null},{Content-Length=[780], Content-Type=[application/json; charset=utf-16], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/10.0], Date=[Tue, 23 Jul 2024 05:23:45 GMT]}>

I receive the above expected response when I change the return to 'Object.class' but as I said earlier I can't make that change. I have also made the following changes in my application.yml  file:
spring.mandatoryFileEncoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true

And following changes in pom.xml:
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

But nothing works for me. Kindly suggest me is there any possible solution to get the response in JSON format without making changes in the code.
TIA.

Looks like regular ASCII got decoded as UTF-16 somewhere. Might be the String constructor - if you’re just passing it a single array of bytes, those will be interpreted as UTF-16.

@nneonneo
Can you be more explanatory, I couldn't get what you are trying to say?

This question is similar to: Rest template.exchange returns response as junk while doing a GET request to a server running REST service in dot net core. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Might also be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27603782/1204143, which appears to offer a clear solution.

Your server is generating text in the UTF-16 charset, as evidenced by the header Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-16. Unfortunately, UTF-16 is by itself an ambiguous charset: there are two variants, UTF-16-BE ("big endian") and UTF-16-LE ("little endian").
Normally, if only "UTF-16" is specified, the first two bytes of the response should be a byte order mark, either FF FE or FE FF, signifying the endian used to encode the message. However, your server is not sending the byte order mark. Therefore, Spring ends up having to guess which endianness is being used - and Spring is guessing wrong.
I can demonstrate that the text is being received with the wrong endianness with a short Python script that "ungarbles" the message you received:
r = r'笀∀爀攀焀甀攀猀琀䐀愀琀攀吀椀洀攀∀㨀∀㈀　㈀㐀ⴀ　㜀ⴀ㈀㌀吀㄀　㨀㈀㄀㨀㄀㠀⸀㜀　㜀㘀㐀㄀㐀⬀　㔀㨀　　∀Ⰰ∀氀漀最䤀搀∀㨀∀㈀㜀　　㄀㜀昀戀ⴀ　攀㤀戀ⴀ㐀㐀戀搀ⴀ㤀搀　㠀ⴀ㔀㔀㄀㄀㌀㔀搀㜀搀　戀昀∀Ⰰ∀挀漀搀攀∀㨀∀䴀匀䜀ⴀ　　　　　　∀Ⰰ∀猀攀瘀攀爀椀琀礀∀㨀∀匀甀挀挀攀猀猀∀Ⰰ∀挀漀渀琀攀渀琀∀㨀∀攀礀䨀栀戀䜀挀椀伀椀䨀䤀唀稀䤀㄀一椀䤀猀䤀渀刀㔀挀䌀䤀㘀䤀欀瀀堀嘀䌀䨀㤀⸀攀礀䨀㄀戀洀氀砀搀圀嘀昀戀洀䘀琀娀匀䤀㘀䤀洀䤀㐀娀䐀䔀㈀䴀圀䔀礀䰀圀夀㈀夀樀挀琀一䐀䴀砀一礀㄀栀夀樀䔀　䰀吀欀㌀䴀䐀最稀伀吀䴀㐀娀圀䔀㐀䴀椀䤀猀䤀洀㔀椀娀椀䤀㘀䴀吀挀礀䴀吀挀砀䴀樀䄀㌀伀䌀眀椀娀堀栀眀䤀樀漀砀一稀䤀砀一稀䔀㄀一樀挀㐀䰀䌀䨀瀀夀堀儀椀伀樀䔀㌀䴀樀䔀㌀䴀吀䤀眀一稀栀㤀⸀挀䤀䄀攀䈀砀ⴀ瘀爀吀娀匀㠀㤀㠀甀㈀䄀㔀娀䰀㔀䴀倀䔀愀　爀欀伀儀瘀堀漀ⴀ樀ⴀ洀䤀礀唀　　∀Ⰰ∀攀爀爀漀爀∀㨀渀甀氀氀紀'
print(r.encode("utf-16-le").decode("utf-16-be"))

This prints {"requestDateTime":"2024-07-23T10:21:18.7076414+05:00","logId":"270017fb-0e9b-44bd-9d08-551135d7d0bf","code":"MSG-000000","severity":"Success","content":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImI4ZDE2MWEyLWY2YjctNDMxNy1hYjE0LTk3MDgzOTM4ZWE4MiIsIm5iZiI6MTcyMTcxMjA3OCwiZXhwIjoxNzIxNzE1Njc4LCJpYXQiOjE3MjE3MTIwNzh9.cIAeBx-vrTZS898u2A5ZL5MPEa0rkOQvXo-j-mIyU00","error":null}, which is a perfectly reasonable JSON response.
Unfortunately, in this situation it's your server that is not sending proper responses, and should be fixed (if possible). The server should either:

Send a UTF-16 response with a proper byte order mark to indicate the endian used
Set the charset to either UTF-16-LE or UTF-16-BE to explicitly indicate the endian used
Just use UTF-8 and avoid this mess entirely (recommended)

I am not sure it's easy to fix Spring to use the "correct" encoding, unfortunately, as it is your server that is in violation of the relevant specifications.

Oddly enough, r.encode( "utf-16-be").decode( "utf-16-le") == r.encode( "utf-16-le").decode( "utf-16-be") returns True …

Yes, that's because both are just flipping the endianness - which is just swapping each pair of bytes. That's why they produce the same result. (It is for this reason that I don't even know what the actual server encoding was originally - only that it's the opposite of the one used to decode the text).
